# Python: Two Nested Loops

Tags: python, version

I'm trying to find coding for Python version 3 doing these two things in basic coding (a loop nested inside another loop). I understand the basic premise of:

```
    for i in range(10)
        for j in range(10)
```

but I think it's the "i+___" math that's giving me trouble. I'm having trouble giving me these three types of outputs:

First:

```
    0
    0 1
    0 1 2
    0 1 2 3
```

Second:

```
    10
    11 12
    13 14 15
    16 17 18 19
```

Third:

```
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
    2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not sure what is your issue, not compiling because of the missing semi-column? arithmetic works fine but I have no idea what you are trying to do, please clarify if you want a useful answer

Comment: I was just giving an example of the basic code I'm trying to use. I understand there needs to be a semi-column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python version 3.

First:

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(j, end="")
    print()
```

Second:

```
x=10
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(x,i+x):
        print(str(j)+" ", end="")
    x+=i
    print()
```

Third:

```
for i in range(3):
    print((str(i)+" ")*9)
```

Comment: Thank you this is awesome. Please see my edit on #2, I caught a mistake I made. Do you know how to do it this way as well?

Comment: If this satisfies your query then please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Third:

```
j=[]
for i in xrange(0,3):
     j.append([i]*9)
```